# Client application socket closed after printing string

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm building a Java client application which needs to send a message to a server and receive a response afterwards. I can send the message successfully, the problem is that I can't get the response because I get an IO exception ("Socked is closed") when trying to read the 'BufferedReader'.

This is my code, so far:

```
public class MyClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        try {
            j.put("comando", 1);
            j.put("versao", 1);
            j.put("senha", "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b");
            j.put("usuario", "1");
            j.put("deviceId", "1");

        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            System.out.println("JSON Exception reached");
        }

        String LoginString = "{comando':1,'versao':1,'senha':'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b','usuario':'1','deviceId':'1'}";
        try {
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("10.1.1.12", 3333);
            System.out.println("Connected to the server successfully");
            PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);

            outToServer.println(j.toString());
            outToServer.close();
            System.out.println("TO SERVER: " + j.toString());

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String resposta = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + resposta);

            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the server [Unknown exception]");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

I know that the socket is being closed because of the **OutToServer.close()** but closing the stream is the only way to send the message. How should I approach this situation?

Comment: Are you sure closing the stream is the only way to send the message? There's the flush() method, and it is even unnecessary since you're building PrintWriter with the second parameter (autoFlush) set to true. I can't get your point. PS: do you have server code?

Answer (score 2):

`flush()` is not the case when it comes with `new PrintWriter(, true)`.

The real problem is that you are closing the `PrintWriter outToServer` which wraps the underlying `InputStream`, again, came from the `Socket`.

When you close the `outToServer` you're closing the whole socket.

You have to use [Socket#shutdownOutput()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput%28%29).

You don't even have to close the output if you want to keep the socket's in/out channels for further communications.

1. `flush()` when you are done with any `writeXXX`. Those `writeXXX` practically don't mean you sent those bytes and characters to other side of the socket.
2. You may have to close the **output, and output only,** to signal the server that you sent all you had to send. This is really a matter of the server-side socket's desire.

```
final Socket socket = new Socket(...);
try {
    final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    // write here
    out.flush(); // this is important.
    socket.shutdownOutput(); // half closing

    // socket is still alive

    // read input here

} finally {
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: +1 Most likely this is the solution. `shutdownOutput()` will flush the output buffers on TCP level.

Comment: @GaborSch Thank you for your patience against my [Konglish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konglish)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `outToServer.flush()`

That will try to flush the data from the buffer, although it still not guarantees that it will be sent.

Comment: That's correct, still I point that he is constructing PrintWriter with autoFlush=true so flush() should be called automatically upon every println. There's something strange going on. blacblu did you try to test the server behaviour by opening a telnet session? Do you have the server code? Is there any client that actually works with the server? Maybe you get a closed socket because the server fails with an exception.

Comment: Nice catch. I was trying to extract the communication protocol of a server and using another server to test my client, the server I made using .NET to test my client was faulty. I closed it and opened the legit server and got the response as expected. Thank you

Comment: @blacblu There may be some TCP-level problem then, probably the client does not send the packet until a full TCP packet is filled. Try to send some extra data, for example 3000 spaces, that will fill it up. After that, do a `flush()`